# ipad application as hybrid application

Tags: ipad, cordova

I need to develop an iPad application using phonegap(as an hybrid application). I am completely new to this.

I have done some sample in android using html5 css and js with JqueryMobile and phonegap. And some sample in Visual Studio without using Phonegap. So is there anything specific that I need to check creating an app in iPhone vs iPad?

creating an ipad application is same as iPhone application? what all things I need to note down ? please help me..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Basically is the same.
If you are going to use jquery mobile, I suppose they will handle different screen sizes for you.
If not, you should have 2 different css files, one for iPhone and other for iPad (using media queries) and use responsive web design to adjust the UI to the different screens.